# Stop VPN access from wifi router

Tags: vpn, proxy

Is it possible to stop VPN access for all devices when you are the administrator of the wireless connection?

Comment: It's going to depend on the functions of the wifi device and the firewalls you have available. Is this a home network or a company network?

Comment: @schroeder Dear! it's a home network.

Comment: Then the answer is "it is possible, if your equipment gives you that level of control and depending on the type of VPN used"

Comment: Can i have a personal contact with you?

Comment: We don't encourage private, off-site contact - we do have chat rooms here that we use, though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105334/discussion-on-question-by-yaseen-khan-stop-vpn-access-from-wifi-router).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only up to a point.

You can block well-known VPN ports and may even block known VPN protocols with certain protocol characteristics.

You cannot block VPNs without any protocol characteristics or just VPN over HTTPS.